# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ode_modulesue-loaderlibcomponent-normalizer'

Tags: vue.js, package.json

I've recently decided to give `vue-cli` a go but after I run `npm install`, running `npm run dev` gives me the following error.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:Projects  estapp
ode_modulesue-loaderlibcomponent-normalizer' in 'D:\Projects\testapp\src'
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error by reinstalling previous version.

```
 npm install vue-loader@10.0.0 --save-dev
```